# Backup and restore whole system with TAR issue

Tags: permissions, backup, tar

This happened a few times. So I am curious why.

For some purpose, I did `tar cf /backup/os.tar / --one-file-system`. Then booted into rescue system and remade root filesystem. Then `tar xf /backup/os.tar`. And `sendmail` could not work. Either was `lightdm` and `unity`.

Watched various logs for a day, I figured out the root cause. All was because of permission was changed for some files. For example, `/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` was not executable. `/var/lib/sendmail/` belongs to wrong group.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `-p` in your tar command.

```
-p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
                             extract information about file permissions
                             (default for superuser)
```

Comment: So I am confused. I ran my command with `sudo`, I thought that applied "default for superuser".

Comment: Yes, you must use `sudo` for your `tar` command.